# J-query animation with delay and page resize

Tags: jquery, css, animation, resize

So I have created this page with some headings and I wanted to add some jquery animations, a simple text going from left(out of the screen) sliding rightward on the page.

I would like to:

1 - add some delays.
The nav starting the animation immediately when the page is loaded
some headers popout some seconds later and so on with other ones, but I have no idea where to add the delay (timeout) in the script, how can i do that?

2 - I have noticed that the size of the document gets larger and larger during animation and I think this is quite normal, but when the animation is done, the background remains enlarged (there is a bottom sidebar showing the right side of the page) showing a large amount of empty and unused space (that I want to avoid showing). Is there a way to to get an automatic resize when the animation is done?

this is the animation with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var navAni= $("nav");
    navAni.animate({top:'60px'}, 500);
    navAni.animate({top:'30px'}, 500);
        });
          
          $(document).ready(function() {
        var navAni= $("h2");
    navAni.animate({left:'850px'}, 500);
    navAni.animate({left:'600px'}, 500);
        });
          
          $(document).ready(function() {
        var navAni= $("h3");
    navAni.animate({left:'680px'}, 500);
    navAni.animate({left:'600px'}, 500);
        });
          
          $(document).ready(function() {
        var navAni= $("h4");
    navAni.animate({left:'680px'}, 500);
    navAni.animate({left:'600px'}, 500);
        });
```

and some css code for you to understand how it was done:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    align-items: center;
    position:relative;
}

h2 {
    font-size:35px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -580px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color:black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: -580px;
    color:black;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: -580px;
    color:black;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will run into some future issues trying to do these kind of animations with only jQuery animate() as it's limited in what it offers. I'd recommend updating your animations to CSS keyframe animations, or use a JS library like [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) which offers the ability to do all sorts of animations, time them so they run after each other in a timeline and use some of their built-in easing if you want that bounce effect. You can also easily adjust the timing so they can run while previous animations are running, or add delays between each animation. I included code for how I would do it for an example with some basic HTML for how I figured yours was structured viewing your CSS.

As far as #2, you can use JS to adjust the size of your elements after they are done animating if you wish. I just did it with CSS in my example because I know the headings would finish at 50px from the left of the document, so setting width to `calc(100% - 50px)` did the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  nav = $("nav"),
    heading2 = $("h2"),
    heading3 = $("h3"),
    heading4 = $("h4"),
    easeBounce = Back.easeOut.config(2),
    tl = gsap.timeline({});

  //Nav animation
  tl.fromTo(nav, {
    y: '-60px'
  }, {
    duration: 0.75,
    ease: easeBounce,
    y: '30px'
  }),
  //Heading 2 animation
  tl.fromTo(heading2, {
    x: '-100%'
  }, {
    duration: 0.75,
    ease: easeBounce,
    x: '50px'
  })
  //Heading 3 animation
  tl.fromTo(heading3, {
    x: '-100%'
  }, {
    duration: 0.75,
    ease: easeBounce,
    x: '50px'
  })
  //Heading 4 animation
  tl.fromTo(heading4, {
    x: '-100%'
  }, {
    duration: 0.75,
    ease: easeBounce,
    x: '50px'
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  /* margin-top:-60px; */
  /* margin-left: 320px; */
  /* float: left; */
  /* width: 500px; */
  /* height: 50px; */
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* margin-left: -580px; */
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: black;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* margin-left: -580px; */
  color: black;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* margin-left: -580px; */
  color: black;
}


/*
 * New CSS
 */
nav {
  display: block;
}
h2,h3,h4 {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<nav>I'm the navigation</nav>
<h2>I'm heading 2</h2>
<h3>I'm heading 3</h3>
<h4>I'm heading 4</h4>
```